# Adding images/subtexts to listbox control wpf

Tags: vb.net

How do you add images(from resources) beside a listbox item?

Pseudocode:

```
1. Set image of Listbox1.items.item(0) = My.Resources.image0
2. Set image of Listbox1.items.item(1) = My.Resources.image1
```

Comment: Use a ListView - ListBox has a single column.  ListView has multiple columns - put the object in the first column and the image in the second column.

Comment: Try Looking into [OwnerDrawn ListBox](http://www.bing.com/search?q=owner+draw+listbox+.net&form=OSDSRC)